# UIView Taking Long Time To Load (Spritekit & AdMob)

Tags: swift3, uiview, admob

I want to make a game when it's game over, a banner ad shows up, but I found out that the view takes at least one minute to load. I tried doing this on a different thread but it didn't work. I created the view in GameViewController.swift, and added the subview in the GameScene.swift. Also the Game Over Pop up is a set of SKSpriteNodes and SKLabelNodes.

**GameViewController.swift**

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("READY__$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$_________________.")

        banner = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeFullBanner)
        banner.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"

        let request = GADRequest()
        banner.load(request)

        banner.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (view?.bounds.height)! - banner.frame.size.height, width: banner.frame.size.width, height: banner.frame.size.height)

        banner.rootViewController = self

        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "IntroScene") {
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                // Present the scene
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }

            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
        }
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return .allButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .all
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

**GameScene.swift**

```
func spawnAd() {

    print("READY___________________.")
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        self.view?.addSubview(banner)
    })




    //        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
    //            DispatchQueue.main.async {
    //                self.view?.addSubview(banner)
    //            }
    //
    //        }

}
```

The Game Over Screen Pop up

```
func spawnGameOverMenu() {

    let dimPanel = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.brown, size: self.size)
    dimPanel.alpha = 0.0
    dimPanel.zPosition = 9
    dimPanel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
    self.addChild(dimPanel)

    let fadeAlpha = SKAction.fadeAlpha(by: 0.5, duration: 0.6)
    dimPanel.run(fadeAlpha)

    gameOverMenu = SKSpriteNode(color: bgColor, size: CGSize(width: self.frame.width - 5, height: self.frame.height / 2))
    gameOverMenu.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.minY - self.frame.height)
    gameOverMenu.name = "gameOverMenu"
    gameOverMenu.zPosition = 10
    self.addChild(gameOverMenu)
    spawnGameOverLabel()
    spawnResetLbl()

    spawnAd()

    let moveUp = SKAction.moveTo(y: self.frame.midY, duration: 1.0)

    gameOverMenu.run(moveUp)

}
```

Comment: What takes a long time to load, the banner or the start of the app?

Comment: the banner, but I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why it wasn't working, I set the root view controller after I loaded the request.

banner = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeFullBanner)
        banner.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"

banner.rootViewController = self

```
    let request = GADRequest()
    banner.load(request)

    banner.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (view?.bounds.height)! - banner.frame.size.height, width: banner.frame.size.width, height: banner.frame.size.height)
```